# heap size error Aspose

Tags: java, aspose, aspose.words

while converting a docx file in pdf file using Aspose i got this `heap size` error.here is the code
this docx file is 44Mb

```
public void convertDoc(String Path, String destPath) throws Exception{


        Document doc = new Document(Path); //At this line heap size error comes
        doc.save(destPath);
        System.out.println("doc converted to pdf");

        }
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: try to increase the heap size 
somthing like 
java -Xmx512M myprogram

Comment: you mean OutOfMemoryException?

Comment: @BhavikShah yes heap size error is basically outofmemory error.

Comment: @aymankoo can you please explain how can I make my things working by your suggested `something`?

Comment: are you using eclipse?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Increasing the heap size should fix the issue.

If it doesn't, then check if you have high resolution images in your Word document. I have converted very large DOC files to PDF (without high res images) under 512 MB memory. But, some of the documents, even less than 50 pages, but having large sized images, they require large memory, even upto 3GB!!

Possible solutions:

- Replace the images inside your document using Aspose.Words with smaller, resized images
- If the document has multiple sections, split the document by section and convert to PDF separately. This would of course later require the merging of PDF files.

I work as a Developer/Evangelist at Aspose.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are loading a document larger than the heap size you will have to increase the heap size while running the program like this

```
 java -Xmx512M myprogram
```

If you are using eclipse go to `Run -> Run Configurations` and under Arguments Tab type -Xmx512m and click on RUN

[image]